# Create New Admin Menu Section - Like how custom post type works, in a way

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I've been working with Wordpress off and on for years now, but I haven't gotten entirely immersed with the framework. I have no problem creating plugins that use custom post types, but I'm looking to add a new section in the admin that isn't for posts, but rather my own custom tables.

I know how to create the custom tables on installation of the plugin, I'm just looking for the right information to create a new menu section with subsections, but I'm having a hard time finding the answer.

What functions/hooks do I need? I'll figure out the rest after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Administration Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) section in the Codex, I actually used it pretty heavily over the last couple days to create a sub-menu and it helped a lot. It goes into detail on the top level menus as well.

You'll specifically need the [add_menu_page() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to create the top level menu, as well as the [add_submenu_page() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) to create the sub menus. From there it's just a matter of meticulously adding options and setting fields.

Also of great help in understanding the flow of things was [Otto's WordPress Settings API Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/).

Comment: I just found the functions a bit ago and was trying to get them to work, but they weren't showing because the role I selected isn't formatted correctly. I wish the Codex would spell out what it expect sometimes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of working code i used for my project. i placed this code in a file residing within 'lib' folder. you can also write in your functions file.

```
$themename = "Ondeweb";
$shortname = "odwb";
$position = '63.3'; 
$file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
$icon = $file_dir."/images/wand.png";

add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', 'ondeweb-now', 'ondeweb_admin', $icon, $position);
}

function innUbud_add_subpage() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        'ondeweb-now' 
        , 'Ads List' 
        , 'Advertisement List'
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'ondeweb-now-advertise'
        , 'advertiseList'
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'ondeweb-now' 
        , 'Home page videos' 
        , 'Home page videos'
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'ondeweb-now-videos'
        , 'videoList'
    );

}

function advertiseList() {  
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/advertise.php' );
}

function videoList() {  
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/videos.php' );
}
```

in the above code, 'ondeweb-now' is the slug for parent menu which is the indication of parent menu for the sub-menus slug (ondeweb-now-advertise & ondeweb-now-videos)

for detailed explanation these are right places to be:- [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) & [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)